# MongoDB - Perform aggregations on bucketed data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have a collection of nested documents, divided into buckets belonging to a single business id.

To illustrate, the following represents a document related to an invoice from business n. 1022 in which 10 roses, 20 oranges and 15 apples were sold:

```
sample_doc = {
'business_id': '32044',
'dt_op': Timestamp('2018-10-02 12:16:12'),
'transactions': [
    {'Product name': 'Rose', "Quantity": 10},
    {'Product name': 'Orange', "Quantity": 20},
    {'Product name': 'Apple', "Quantity": 15}
    ]
}
```

I would like to get the total number of sales (sum of 'Quantity') for each product ('Product name') within a defined 'business_id'.

I tried, using Compass, to:

```
# Stage 1: $match
{
  business_id: "1022"
}

#Stage 2: $group
{
  _id: "$transactions.Product name",
  TotalSum: {
    $sum: "transactions.Quantity"
  }
}
```

But a nested list of documents is returned, without performing sums.

How can I correctly perform the aggregation pipeline to get the total number of sales (sum of 'Quantity') for each product ('Product name') within a defined 'business_id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, all you're missing is a single [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) before the `$group` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      business_id: "1022"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$transactions"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$transactions.Product name",
      TotalSum: {
        $sum: "$transactions.Quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m0XIn4irDlD)

Comment: Thank you; your intuition is fine although it should be:

[
    {
        '$match': {
            'business_id': '32044'
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$transactions', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$transactions.Product name', 
            'TotalSum': {
                '$sum': '$transactions. Quantity'
            }
        }
    }
]

Comment: Actually both `$unwind` versions will produce the exact same output, which is why I choose the more efficient one that discards the empty objects. feel free to go to the playground link and play with it yourself.

Comment: Perfect; thank you